# socket.io - Use of const in strict mode when require socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Im following the Getting Started Tutorial on socket.io but when i came to the point of including socket.io itself, im getting an error while running the server in the console.

What am I missing?

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Error:

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/server/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:177
  const keysIterator = this.parentNsps.keys();
  ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nginx/html/server/index.js:3:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Comment: What version of node are you using? It looks like you're using a pre-ES2015 version that isn't fully compliant to the specification.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im using v11.2.0. Its freshly installed :/

Comment: Oh but i figured somethign weird. when i type "node -v" its v11.2.0 and "nodejs -v" is v0.10.25

Comment: I just want to double check, and maybe I'm pulling on the wrong thread here, but can you confirm that by running [`console.log(process.version);`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_version) at the top of your program?

Comment: it tells me node: "0.10.25"

Comment: There's your problem then. I don't believe node.js has full ES2015 support until version 6.x. You can run `where nodejs` in the command prompt to get the location of the old install and uninstall it in System Settings.

Comment: Thanks now it works when i start my server with node . but i still have the command "nodejs" installed. Any ideas? nodejs -v returns a different version than node -v